# Unable to use two different Buttons in Tkinter for performing tasks on the same chrome window which I have opened from Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tkinter, selenium-chromedriver

Selenium driver is working in my first button but when i click the second button which tries to use selenium driver for calling the active window it does not work. It says driver is not defined. Is there any solution to this problem? So that I can use the window opened by the driver from the previous button click to perform other functions.

```
def myTask1():   
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path)
    driver.get("#any website")
    #login to any website using username and password then keep that window open
    window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
    window_before_title = driver.title

button_text1 = StringVar()    
button1 = Button(root,textvariable = button_text1,text="Click me", padx=8, pady=8, width="20", command=myTask1)
button_text1.set("Open the Website")
button1.place(relx=.48, rely=.3, anchor=CENTER) 
   
def myTask2():   
    driver.switch_to.window(window_before)
    #main selenium function to perform


button_text2 = StringVar()    
button2 = Button(root,textvariable = button_text2,text="Click me",padx=8, pady=8, width="20", command=myTask2)
button_text2.set("perform function ")
button2.place(relx=.48, rely=.6, anchor=CENTER)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: please include the code for better understanding

Comment: now in my second task i am unable to recall the selenium driver which is working fine for the first task @CoolCloud

Comment: see i think the issue is cuz ur defining the `driver` variable in first function and it stays inside first function only and ur using a method of it in second function where it is not defined nw . So try defining driver again by copying tht code into second function or try saying `global driver` in first function

Comment: @CoolCloud i tried defining the driver once more in the second task then it creates one more instance of googlechrome. sure i will try defining as global driver in first function

Comment: @CoolCloud thanks defining a global variable solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By saying `global driver` you can use the same driver in first function in the second function too. The driver variable is defined in first function and it stays inside first function only and your using a method of it in second function where it is not defined nw. So saying `global driver` will make it available to the second function as well